# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01858: date time false format

Tags: python, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, cx-oracle

I'm trying to get my head around the error message I receive when I parse a date/time parameter such as:

```
'29-SEP-1999 14:00:00'
```

as opposed to:

```
'29-SEP-1999'
```

The former doesn't insert into the table, the latter does. I suspect there is an issue with the NLS settings, but the settings are not so clear as to what format of a date/time is permitted, and so subsequently what I need to reformat in the date/time, in my python code. My current setting for NLS on SQL Developer are:

```
Date format: DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF
```

Here is my code:

```
sql_insert = 'insert into sms_temtplate_test (date_sms, result_sms, msgid, msgparts) values (:1, :2, :3, :4)'
smsreport_text_new = ('29-SEP-1989 14:00:00', 'success', '2D67A865FBHFA25A9261C75E8D2F0F2B ', 1)

cursor.execute(sql_insert, smsreport_text_new)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: NLS Setting on your SQL Developer will not play any role, Can you post the actual code where you are inserting the date.

Comment: Original post amended, see above

Comment: instead of `'29-SEP-1989 14:00:00'` try `TO_DATE('29-SEP-1989 14:00:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`

Comment: In my script I amended this to :               smsreport_text_new = ('''TO_DATE('29-SEP-1959 14:00:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')''', 'success', '2D557A865FBHFA25A9261C75E8D2F0F2B ', 1), still didn't work

Comment: what is the exact error message you receive.

Comment: I figured it out. I need also to amend the sql_insert to the following: sql_insert = """insert into xura_temtplate_test (date_sms, result_sms, msgid, msgparts) values (TO_DATE(:1, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), :2, :3, :4)"""

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

`to_date('29-sep-1999 14:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`

If you really want to insert the string without specifying the format you can issue the following:

`alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'`

You can also convert that string to a datetime.datetime instance in Python and then simply bind that to your SQL statement.